# Возникли вопросы по Metadata в MEF

Tags: c#, .net, плагин, addons, mef

Немного не понял, как работает Metadata в MEF.

1. В этом примере приводится атрибут ExportMetada https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx

Как MEF понимает, что он относится к IOperationData ? Там же в атрибуте явно не прописывается контракт.
Получается, что за счет этого только понимает `IEnumerable<Lazy<IOperation, IOperationData>> operations;` к чему относится метада?
С толку сбивает неявность.

2. Если я правильно понял, то можно задавать несколько методат(которые относятся к разным контрактам). Как их в таком случае можно их прочитать?
3. Обязательно использовать `Lazy<T,MetaData>`, что бы получить доступ к метадате?
4. Где прочитал, что это лишь 1 из способов(с помощью атрибута) задания метадаты.
   Какие еще есть способы?